Probability of the dice sum is equal to $18$

You roll four dice and take the sum of the three highest values. What is the probability that the sum is equal to $18$?

My thought process:
We need the sum of the greatest three rolls to be $18$, which is only possible if we roll three $6$s. The fourth roll can be any number from $1$ through $6$. Also, the fourth number can occur in any of the four rolls, hence, we multiply $4$. And finally, the probability,
$$P = 4 \times \frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{6} \times \frac{6}{6} = \frac{1}{54}.$$
Does this look right?

You have 4 dice (blue, red, green,yellow) ; Q1)What is the proba that all of them roll a 6; Q2)What is the proba that blue,red,green roll a 6, and yellow does not roll a 6. Q3)Conclude.

This is not correct.  The problem comes from the case of four sixes, which can only be obtained in $1$ way, not $4$.
Thinking of the total roll as an ordered quadruple, there are $6^4$ possible total rolls.  Of these, the good ones are $(6,6,6,6)$ and all permutations of $(X,6,6,6)$ where $X\in \{1,\cdots, 5\}$.  There are $4\times 5=20$ of the latter sort, so $21$ good rolls all in all.  Thus the answer is $$\frac {21}{6^4}=\frac 7{432}\approx .0162$$
which is slightly less than $\frac 1{54}\approx .0185$.

Thank you so muchh!!

You can view the problem as sampling with replacement: 
What is the probability that at least 3 dice out of 4 come up with 6?
Let random variable $X$ be the number of 6's obtained from 4 dice rolls, $X$ has a binomial distribution and the probability for at least 3 is:
$$\begin{align}Pr(X\geq3)&= {4 \choose 3}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^3\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^1 + {4 \choose 4}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^4\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^0\\ &= 4\cdot\frac{5}{6^4} +\frac{1}{6^4} \\ & = \frac{21}{6^4} \approx .0162 \end{align}$$
Again, this accounts for the "quadruple 6" happening only once, which you accidentally forgot! We get the same answer as @lulu's, but this one is more utilising a formula, which could be useful to learn! You can find out more by searching for "binomial distribution" :)

Got it. Thank you!!
